# Excluding a slide from the slide count in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007, slideshow, numbering, exclude

In a PowerPoint presentation, I use numbered slides. As a good practice, I repeat the index (TOC) between chapters, in order to enable the audience to keep up with the structure of my speech.

However, I want to exclude the repeating slide from the numbering sequence. I can just remove the slide number, but that only creates a gap between two slides, i.e. the numbering goes 1 - 2 - 4 - etc...

How can I exclude a slide from the slide numbering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerPoint's numbering isn't up to this, unfortunately.

You'd have to create the numbers manually.

Or use a bit of VBA to do the job for you.  If you've got a bit of VBA experience, you could have a go at this and if you need help, ask in StackOverflow (this forum's sibling).